# Is $f^{-1}(E)\subset M \iff f^{-1}(\sigma(E))\subset M$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given $f:(X,M)\rightarrow(Y,N)$. Under what condition does $f^{-1}(E)\subset M \iff f^{-1}(\sigma(E))\subset M$ where $E\subset P(Y)$? Is this true in general? If not, how about one direction?

Answer (score 0):

This is always true.

You need this lemma:

> Let $f:(X,\mathcal M)\to (Y,\mathcal N)$ and $\mathcal E\subset \mathcal P(Y)$. Then $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))=f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))$

- $\fbox{$\subset$}$ Since $\sigma(\mathcal E)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra,  $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))$ is a $\sigma$-algebra as well, and it's easy to check that $f^{-1}(\mathcal E)\subset f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))$. Therefore $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))\subset f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))$.
- $\fbox{$\supset$}$ Let $\mathcal{S}=\{B\in\mathcal{P}(Y)\; ; \;f^{-1}(B)\in\sigma\left(f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{E}\right)\right)\}$. You can check that $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal E$. As a result $\sigma(\mathcal E) \subset \mathcal S$, that is to say $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))\subset \sigma\left(f^{-1}\left(\mathcal{E}\right)\right)$.

---

Now, if $f^{-1}(\mathcal E)\subset \mathcal M$, since $\mathcal M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))\subset \mathcal M$ and the previous lemma yields $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))\subset \mathcal M$.

Conversely, if $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal E))\subset \mathcal M$, the lemma yields $\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal E))\subset \mathcal M$, hence $f^{-1}(\mathcal E)\subset \mathcal M$

Answer (score 0):

Obviously.

Let $f:\Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$, then $f^{-1}$ is closed for complement, union and intersection in $\Omega_1$.

Since $\mathcal N$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\sigma (E)\subset\mathcal N$ ,naturally $f^{-1}(E)\subset \mathcal M$ and $f^{-1}[\sigma (E)]\subset \mathcal M$